# Android dynamic onClick buttons from sensor list using tags

Tags: android, button, dynamic, tags, sensors

Sorry for asking again, but I wasn't able to implement the "tag" function to my dynamic onClick buttons from a sensor list.

As you can see I have selected my button tag based on the type of sensor and it set the tag accordingly. However when I try to work out the onClick function it doesn't work, scroll down to see it. The program has no errors and when I press the button, the Toast doesn't show up.

Have I implemented by get tag correctly?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener, OnClickListener  {
String tag;
TextView myTextView;    
SensorManager mySensorManager;
TextView status;
String btn = "button";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mySensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);

    List<Sensor> myList = mySensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_tags);


    for (int i = 1; i < myList.size(); i++) {
            myTextView.append("\n" + myList.get(i).getName());

            Button btnTag = new Button(this);
            btnTag.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            btnTag.setText(myList.get(i).getName());
            btnTag.setId(i);
            btnTag.setTag(myList.get(i).getName());
            layout.addView(btnTag);
           ((Button) findViewById(i)).setOnClickListener(this);
           // btnTag.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     tag = (String) v.getTag(); 
if (tag == "Goldfish 3-axis Magnetic field sensor")
    {
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Button1 is Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I just added another toast message to display when onClick is pressed. So the listener works. It's just I doesn't work with specific tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot compare strings with `==`.  `Strings` are objects and `==` tests whether two object references are the same object.

You need `equals()` which compares string values.

```
 if ((tag.equals("Goldfish 3-axis Magnetic field sensor"))
```

On a technical (geek) curiosity,`==` *might* work - sometimes -  due to [string interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning), and can lead to some obscure bugs when it's used when `.equals()` should be used.